# Use gmail to send email: Using System.Web.Mail

Tags: c#, smtp

Web.Mail is already deprecated and that System.Net.Mail is alot easier to use, and it's simplier to integrate it with gmail. But my question is, can i still use the deprecated class sending email (using google's smtp)? Is possible?

Comment: use System.Net.Mail, not the deprecated System.Web.Mail. Doing SSL with System.Web.Mail is a gross mess of hacky extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this url from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.aspx

But still in this they recommend Sytem.Net.Mail.